# Call a function with many arguments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a compose function what should be called with n number of function, depending by what function was added as parameter.
For example:

```js
const props = ['link', 'letter'];

const mapp = {
  letter: (v) => {
    v + 'letter'
  },
  link: (v) => {
    v + 'nr'
  }
}

const compose = (...fns) =>
  fns.reduce(
    (prevFn, nextFn) =>
    (...args) =>
    nextFn(prevFn(...args)),
    (value) => value,
  );


const res = compose(props);

console.log(res('test'))
```

So, i expect, if the `const props = ['link', 'letter'];` the `compose` function should be called like: `const res = compose(mapp[letter], mapp[link]);`, or if `const props = ['letter'];`, the compose function should be called as: `compose(mapp[letter])`. At the moment the code does not work as expeted. 
 Question: How to fix the code and to get the expected result?

Comment: what is your expected result and BTW both `letter` and `link` property of `mapp` that are functions are returning nothing. Is this correct? I mean what is it for?

Answer (score 2):

There was 2 problems with your code

1. Missing `return` statement(s) in the `mapp` object's functions (or remove the `{` and `}` - see below)
2. You needed to `map` the string array into references to the functions and spread (`...`) the result when calling `compose`

Working example:

```js
const props = ['link', 'letter'];

const mapp = {
  letter: (v) => {
    return v + 'letter'
  },
  link: (v) => {
    return v + 'nr'
  }
}

const compose = (...fns) =>
  fns.reduce(
    (prevFn, nextFn) => (...args) => nextFn(prevFn(...args)),
    (value) => value,
  );


const res = compose(...props.map(p => mapp[p]));
console.log(res('test'))
```

Regarding 1. above that object could be written as below:

```
const mapp = {
  letter: (v) => v + 'letter',
  link: (v) => v + 'nr'
}
```

---

Edit: The need to destructure the call to `map` is because of the way you defined `compose` to take discrete parameters rather than an array. ie, this would also work (and not need to destructure `map`)

```js
const props = ['link', 'letter'];

const mapp = {
  letter: (v) => {
    return v + 'letter'
  },
  link: (v) => {
    return v + 'nr'
  }
}

const compose = (fns) => /// compose now takes an array of functions
  fns.reduce(
    (prevFn, nextFn) => (...args) => nextFn(prevFn(...args)),
    (value) => value,
  );


const res = compose(props.map(p => mapp[p]));
console.log(res('test'))
```

Comment: why `...props.map(p => mapp[p])`, but not `props.map(p => mapp[p])` ? why do we need to destructure ?

Comment: @Asking because as you said in your question you need it to be like `const res = compose(mapp[letter], mapp[link]);` - if you dont destructure its more like `const res = compose([mapp[letter], mapp[link]]);` which will wok, you just need to change your `compose` method to `compose(fns){}` not `compose(...fns){}`

Comment: got you. Thanks

Comment: @Asking Updated answer with some detail.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see how you are using the object with the functions and you are not returning correctly in a few places. It should look something like

```js
const props = ['link', 'letter'];

const mapp = {
  letter: (v) => v + 'letter',
  link: (v) => v + 'nr',
}

const compose = (obj, fns) => (...orgArgs) => 
  fns.reduce((args, fnName) => obj[fnName].apply(obj, [args]), orgArgs);

const res = compose(mapp, props);

console.log(res('test'))
```